# Batch several sequences for absent restriction sites

Tags: bioinformatics, lab-techniques, sequence-analysis, restriction-enzymes

I have a collection of about 120 7kB sequences I would like to check for ether a list of specific restriction sites, or what restriction sites might be absent in all of them.

**Is there a app or library that can do this?**

So far I've only found systems that can do 1 or 2 sequences at a time.

Possible workaround:
Right now I'm trying to concatenate all the sequences together (about 850Mb) and then using [Bio.Restrictions](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/cookbook/Restriction.html) methods of the [Biopython libraries](http://biopython.org/wiki/Biopython).  As I kept running into memory overflow problems, I'm refining the search make a new `RestrictionBatch` based on 4-5 enzymes that are absent and introduce-able into 3-4 test sequences.

Even then I'm running into crashes, which will probably mean that I take the complete set and test over five or so combined `strings`.

Before I completely go re-inventing the wheel, can anyone let me know of something that already does this?  I don't really care about the language, we have Python, .Net, Java, R, and MatLab "covered" across the lab.

Comment: Why can't you read in each sequence one at a time, and use regex's to see if the recognition sequences are in there?

Comment: @swbarnes2 I can, but that seems only practical so long as I keep the restrictionbatch small. Vs a real test of hundreds of enzymes is that practical?

Comment: How long do you think it takes to search for 100 regex sequences in one string?  I don't think it will take long.

Comment: @Swbarnes2 that's backing out of using Biopython, but something we're considering. The actual full library we have is about 1200 enzymes, many of which with wildcards. I wanted to make sure something like that didn't already exist before we build it